# check if one of the the elements in propagation has a specific class, on jquery.click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

In `jQuery.click()` method it's possible to get the class of element which has fired the event using `even.target`. I want to check if the element which has been clicked or one of its parent has some specific class.

```
<div class="c1"><a href="#" class="c2">Click</a></div>
<script>

$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).hasClass("c1"))
        alert("It's C1"); 
});

</script>
```

But it always failes because `c2` has been clicked. Despite using `.parent()`, I'm wondering if there is a way to check the propagation on on-click event.

Comment: Why don't you just detect the clicks over C2 if that's what interest you?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/eD2B3/

Comment: @Paulpro Sorry it was just a mistake. I edited the question

Comment: @Omid It works correctly with the typo fixed. What else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Paulpro I made and edit. please check it out

Comment: @Omid I see the edit now, I answered your question below. Please test your questions with a JSFiddle before posting next time, so that we can avoid wasting our time with unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you said is C1 was clicked and you want to know if

You need to see if the element is inside that was clicked.

```
 var target = $(e.target); 
 if (target.hasClass("c2") || target.find(".c2").length) {
    alert("C2 is a child");
 }
```

---

EDIT, now what you orginally asked is not what you really wanted.

Now if it is a parent it is as simple as

```
 var target = $(e.target); 
 if (target.hasClass("c1") || target.parents(".c1").length) {
     alert("C1 child was clicked");
 }
```

or as Ian pointed out

```
 if (target.closest(".c1").length) {
     alert("C1 child was clicked");
 }
```

Comment: `target.find` is useless, because `e.target` never has descendant elements.

Comment: @Paulpro Did you read it, the OP says that C1 has been clicked, not C2 and they want to know if it has an element C2. Probably something weird with the CSS that gets it into that state.

Comment: There were a mistake dudes. I just edited the question.

Comment: @Ovid Is it C1 or C2 that is being registered by event.target? make a test case that shows the problem.

Comment: it's C1 which should be detected

Comment: So c2 is the one that is clicked and console.log(event.target) would be the C1?

Comment: `event.target` is C2 while I want to know if C1 has been clicked

Comment: Your edit can use `.closest(".c1")` instead of both `.hasClass()` and `.parents()`

Comment: I always forget that closest checks itself!

Comment: @epascarello Gotta love it :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$(this).hasClass` instead of $(e.target). Also `$(this).parent()` will lead to parent of a target